# たくさん並べたButton（９個）、その中で１つのボタンの数値を返したい。

Tags: swift, xcode

[image: button]

上記のように、３個×３個＝９個ボタンのボタンを並べて、その中で最後にタップされたボタンの数値を、戻り値として活かしたと思います。
普通は、UISegmentedControlやUIPickerViewを使うところだとは思いますが、マス目状にボタンがならんだ状態でボタンを使用したいです。
こんなことは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

各９個のボタンにメソッドを紐付ければいいんじゃないでしょうか？

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。試してみます。